# How to get definitions of a term through Google

Tags: google-search

I used to be able to search `define:xyz` on Google, where `xyz` is a term I want defined. It's not working any more or it only shows one result and no link to see the rest. Here's an example:

[image: bad google search]

I tried going to *Search tools* → *All results*,  but I don't have the option dictionary.

[image: no dictionary option under search tools]

I should say that it does return one result but it used to return more than 10 and for words such as "heat" clearly there are going to be more than one definition.

It seems to work from my home computer. Maybe this is a test/problem only affecting US users.